# Non-blocking readline for STDIN?

Tags: ruby, unix, stdin, pipe

I can't figure out why IO methods won't work on STDIN, when properly set to non-blocking mode:

```
  require 'fcntl'

  stdin_flags = STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL)
  p stdin_flags   #32770
  p STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_SETFL, stdin_flags | Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK) # 0
  p STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL)    # 34818
  #at_exit { STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_SETFL, stdin_flags & ~Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK) }
  STDIN.readline    # this call blocks, IO::EAGAINWaitReadable expected
  exit
```

`IO.fcntl` successfully sets non-blocking mode but all IO functions like `read`, `readline`, `gets`, `readchar` ignore the mode and hang at reading when no input has been received.

Setting sync mode to true has no effect.

If I replace `STDIN.readline` with the shell call `system('read line')` it does work correctly. It won't wait or would wait for input depending if non-blocking mode was set.

I'm aware of `IO.read_nonblock` but looking for an efficient way how to read newline terminated strings. Calling `read_nonblock` for each single character is painfully slow.

Can anybody explain this (mis)behavior?

Comment: *@the Tin Man* thanks for text corrections

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit unfortunate but standard functions from `IO` module seem to not respect status flags associated with a file descriptor.

One of the working solutions is use of [`IO.select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-select) class method for input polling, then read the data with regular methods as they become available.
Be aware when line processing methods are used, code may hang until terminating newline character gets consumed. It's advisable to enclose polling code in `Timeout` block when things are going out of control.

In cases when amount of characters/bytes is known beforehand, stock [`IO.read_nonblock`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) would simply serve well.